# Activity - 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, image, android-intent, cursor, gallery

as in title you see, I got a big trouble with 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference  ...
Already reads many posts about that problem but neither of them doesn't solve my problem at all. It was working 2 weeks ago, and I doesn't change anything in my opinion only update AndroidStudios to a new version, and after that comes that kind of bug.

Here is my Code

```
CircleImageView civ;
private final static int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;
private static final String TAG = "GalleryUtil";
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
String picturePath;
ImageView imageView;

        civ.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
            Intent GI = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(GI,RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data !=null && data.getData() != null) {
        try {
            bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();


            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // Bład
            cursor.close();

            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);

            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
            imageView = findViewById(R.id.circle_profile);
            int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
            int targetH = imageView.getHeight();
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;


            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG,"RESULT_CANCELED");
        Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

What it does shortly, I got a Circle Image View like this

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:id="@+id/circle_profile"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/civ"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    />
```

and when I click on default phot it will show my Gallery with some photos that I took, then when I pressed on one of them, *bum* I got crash: cursor is null and already try to fix it but doesn't have any good issues

I'm new with Android, so pls don't tell me there is a solution in this link or this, need clear answers to understand that

/// UPDATE ///

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data !=null && data.getData() != null) {
        try {
            bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(data.getData()), bmOptions);


            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
            imageView = findViewById(R.id.circle_profile);
            int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
            int targetH = imageView.getHeight();
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;


            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(data.getData()), bmOptions));
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions));

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG,"RESULT_CANCELED");
        Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: `NullPointerException`! Dont use `cursor` if it is `null`. Add `if (cursor==null) return;` before curson.moveToFirst().

Comment: Ok but it still doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);
```

Change to

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, bmOptions);
```

And do away with that Cursor to get a file path.

Comment: Now, it working but instead of my photo I get with space

Comment: `I get with space` ??? A white space? No picture to be seen? Please show your new code in a new code block.

Comment: Updated in post, hope its the way that you wanted

Comment: ??? You are still using decodeFile(). But.. sorry i did it wrong... see my updated answer.

Comment: because if I used this decode stream with your value I got "Cannot resolve method 'decodeStream(Uri,android.graphicss.BitmapFactory.Options"

Comment: Well then you should have told me of course. I was wrong with that code. But now i posted the correct code.

Comment: What is this getContentResolver and what should I do with it ?

Comment: Just try those two statements. `Change to`.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'decodeStream(InputStream,BitmapFactroyy.Options)'

Comment: Then let your IDE tell you which extra parameter that function needs. You can supply a null value i think.

Comment: Like this ? BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null); or what you mean

Comment: No. As that has two parameters. You should use the one with three parameters. As i said with an extra parameter.  Your IDE will tell you how that one looks like. Which IDE do you use?

Comment: Android Studio, like this decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect OutPadding, Options opts); so that means  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,bmOptions);

Comment: And we are back to begging, there is no error but photo doesn't show up, it seems that it is here but it is whole white, because I can click again and chose another one